# Avoid "mixture" of color when scrolling

Tags: css, macos, browser, colors

> **Seems to be a Mac only issue.**

I noticed that in in some colors (light ones mainly) when you scroll the browsers, the color mix up and form another one`*`

What do I mean:

See [this list on wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_web_browsers#Browser_features).

When you scroll up and down, the pink squares turn yellow.

Here is an [isolated example](http://www.jsfiddle.net/Trufa/y88JA/2/).

I find this sort of annoying (Maybe because it's friday).

I also noticed that with other more opaque colors this [doesn't happen](http://www.jsfiddle.net/Trufa/y88JA/3/) or is not noticeable.

Has this problem any solution?

Is it a poor choice of colors for web design or is it a browser error?

Does it happen in all browsers?

Thanks in advance!!

```
*Tested in Chrome and Safari (Mac).
```

---

> Sory I can't show any screenshots because this happens **while** scrolling, and can't record it either cause the definition (or fps or smth) is not enough - the problem is quite subtle.

Comment: Can't reproduce in Opera 11, Chromium 8, Chrome 8, Midori 0.2.9, Firefox 3.6.13 on Ubuntu Linux 10.04 and 10.10, nor in IE8 on WinXP sp3. Screenshot?

Comment: Might be a Mac problem, thanks for the heads up! I'll edit. I cant do a screen shot while scrolling, il try to upload a video :)

Comment: This is design/color theory/optical illusion question. Is StackOverflow the place for it? You could get different screen? http://home.swipnet.se/pehrs/English/howcan.htm

Comment: @Krule I don't think that is the cas (IMHO) since I'm not trying to understand what is behind it, rather how to solve a web design problem.

Comment: @Trufa Don't use these colors (red/green) next (especially above or below) to each other. ;) No other solution. However, most people will not notice anyway.

Comment: @Krule Thanks but this is kind of and axe to the middle of the problem! If I don't develop my site I won't have this problem either ;)

Comment: @Trufa: Does this "mix-up" remain there when you stop scrolling? If not (i.e. the colors revert back to normal when you stop scrolling), it may be an optical illusion, and unless you can rewire the brains of your users, there indeed exists no solution to this. If, however, the "mix-up" stays mixed up when you stop scrolling, you may have encountered a browser bug (a strange one, as Webkit-based browsers - Safari, Chrome, Midori - usually give very similar rendering across platforms).

Comment: btw, cannot reproduce in Firefox 4 on Ubuntu Linux 10.10 either.

Comment: @Piskvor The problem is just **while** scrolling, @Krule also suggested it could be an optical illusion but I don't understand how it could be one, should i see that in all browsers then (because it's in my brain not my chrome)?

Comment: @Trufa: Yes, if it is redrawing the viewport quickly enough, you should see this effect in any browser. It's an artifact of human optical signal processing; as such, not really fixable in the browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this "mix-up" persist when you stop scrolling?

If not, it may be an optical illusion - and you will see it in every browser, as long as it's redrawing its viewport quickly enough. Unless you can rewire the brains of your users, there is indeed no solution to that - it's just an artifact of human optical signal processing.

If, however, the "mix-up" stays mixed up when you stop scrolling, you may have encountered a browser bug (a strange one, as Webkit-based browsers usually give very similar rendering across platforms).

Comment: I'm not yet convinced :) (hard-headed me) but you seem to be right!

Answer (score 0):

I can tell you that it doesn't happen in Chrome or Firefox on Windows 7, but does happen in Internet Explorer (though I'm not sure I would have noticed if I hadn't been specifically looking for it), so likely a browser/OS issue.

The solution would probably be to choose colours that this isn't a problem with.

Comment: Which IE? There are numerous versions in use (currently ranging from IE5.5 to IE9), do you mean IE8 (should be default on Win7)?